# Does Subclassing Keras Sequence Require implementing __next__ method?

Tags: python, keras, iterator, sequence-generators

The [Keras Sequence class documentation](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) says

```
Every Sequence must implement the __getitem__ and the __len__ methods. If you 
want to modify your dataset between epochs you may implement on_epoch_end. The 
method __getitem__ should return a complete batch.
```

However the source code for `fit_generator` & other similar methods in [training_generator.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e8946d5240f3b18528d4d34668ee615907879953/keras/engine/training_generator.py) calls `next` method with the generator passed as the argument. From my understanding this means, the class which subclasses from `Sequence` should be an iterator which requires `__next__` method to be implemented.

In order to use a class subclassed from `Sequence` with methods like `fit_generator`, `predict_generator`, etc. is it required to implement `__next__` method?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no need to implement `__next__`, if you carefully check `fit_generator` in `training_generator.py`, you will see that another API is used if the generator is a subclass of `Sequence`, `__next__` is not used for sequences.

This was implemented that way because a `Sequence` can be read by multiple workers, that's why it uses a index-based API and not a stateful API like `__next__`.